# Session.SessionID generate new ID on each post back in IE 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, session-variables

I have created an asp.net page which store user specific data in session variable.

```
string key= Session.SessionID;
Session.Add(key,"myData");
```

Till now I have been **testing it on chrome** and everything **works properly**. But as soon as I started testing it **on IE 10**, the **functionality stops working**. Later on I figured it out that on each post back the **IE returns new value of Session.SessionID** while this value is **persistent in Chrome**.

Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable cookies in IE.

Session works in this way - It depends on client cookie to uniquely identify a client, and it saves the unique value to cookie, and it depends on your web.config setting, if cookieless = false, then it stores in client cookie.

When request comes from a client, it gets your session stored (in server) value using that uniquely identifiable cookie.

If cookie is disabled, it will create new session each time for each request, that is why you are getting new session id every time in IE, as it might have cookie disabled.